# numpy linalg.lstsq with big values

Tags: python, numpy

I'm using linalg.lstsq to build a regression line inside a function like this:

```
def lsreg(x, y):
    if not isinstance(x, np.ndarray):
        x = np.array(x)
    if not isinstance(y, np.ndarray):
        y = np.array(y)
    A = np.array([x, np.ones(len(x))])
    ret = np.linalg.lstsq(A.T, y)
    return ret[0]
```

and calling it like this:

```
x = np.array([10000001, 10000002, 10000003])
y = np.array([3.0, 4.0, 5.0])
regress = lsreg(x, y)
fit = regress[0]*x + regress[1]
print fit
```

and the output y get is:

```
[ 3.  4.  5.]
```

So far, so good. Now, if I change x like this:

```
x = np.array([100000001, 100000002, 100000003])
y = np.array([3.0, 4.0, 5.0])
regress = lsreg(x, y)
fit = regress[0]*x + regress[1]
print fit
```

I get

```
[ 3.99999997  4.00000001  4.00000005]
```

instead of something close to 3, 4 and 5.

Any clue on what is going on ?

Comment: On my computer the jump happens between `[85757491, 85757492, 85757493]` and `[85757501, 85757502, 85757503]`, but I have no idea why.

Comment: Aside: I think you can use `x = np.asarray(x)` instead of the isinstance check.  If `x` is already an `ndarray` it doesn't make a new copy.  Doesn't change anything but is shorter to write.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is due to numerical errors that occur when solving an ill-conditioned system of equations.

```
In [115]: np.linalg.lstsq(A.T, y)
Out[115]: 
(array([  3.99999993e-08,   3.99999985e-16]),
 array([], dtype=float64),
 1,
 array([  1.73205084e+08,   1.41421352e-08]))
```

Notice that np.linalg.lstsq returned "1" for the rank of the matrix AA.T formed from your input matrix. This means it thinks your matrix is rank 1 and hence is ill-conditioned (as your least square system is a 2 x 2 system of equations it should be rank 2). The second singular value which is close to 0 confirms this. This is the reason for the "wrong" result. You should google along the lines of "numerical linear algebra numerical errors" to learn more about this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with scipy:

```
from scipy import stats

x = np.array([100000001, 100000002, 100000003])
y = np.array([3.0, 4.0, 5.0])

res = stats.linregress(x, y)
print x*res[0] + res[1]
```

and I get:

```
[ 3.  4.  5.]
```